# How to get and show counts of values each column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe.

df:

```
   col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
0   1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0
1   NaN  1.0  1.0  2.0  1.0
2   2.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  1.0
```

I want to get the count number of rows that have the same data each column like following.

OutPut:

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1.0    1    2    2    0    3
2.0    1    0    0    1    0
```

or only the count of a value.

```
    col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1.0    1    2    2    0    3
```

Are there any ways to get my expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) method of pandas Series and then [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) for filling `NaN` values with `0`:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0   1.0   1.0   NaN   NaN   1.0
1   NaN   1.0   1.0   2.0   1.0
2   2.0   NaN   1.0   NaN   1.0

In [8]: df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).fillna(0)
Out[8]:
     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
1.0     1   2.0   2.0   0.0   3.0
2.0     1   0.0   0.0   1.0   0.0
```

If you need `int` values instead of float you could also use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) with `int`:

```
In [9]: df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts()).fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[9]:
     col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
1.0     1     2     2     0     3
2.0     1     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: *df.replace(np.NaN, 0) does not work reliably across versions, so updated to use df.fillna(0) instead.*

To count the occurrences of a value in each column use value_counts.  Non-occurring values become NaN, so need to be replaced with 0:

```
>>> df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0)


   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
1     1     2     2     0     3
2     1     0     0     1     0
```

To retrieve a particular row:

```
>>> df.apply(pd.value_counts).fillna(0).loc[1:1]

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
1     1     2     2     0     3
```

Comment: I tried to use replace with np.Nan but it didn't work at the moment. I will investigate the reason, thanks for the information!

Comment: I was surprised it worked since NaN == NaN is False; presumably my version of Pandas has special processing for replacing NaN that yours doesn't have?  I'll update my answer to note this.

Comment: I tried "replace(np.NaN, 0)" again and it worked properly. I think your way should have been working as I didn't investigate the reason at the moment because of being in a hurry. Thank you very much for letting know this way!